# Python (creating a negative of this black and white image)

Tags: python, image, pixel

I am trying to create a negative of this black and white image. The opposite of white (255) is black (0) and vice versa. The opposite of a pixel with a value of 100 is 155.
I cannot use convert, invert, point, eval, lambda.

Here is my code but it doesnt work yet. Could you please let me know which part i am wrong.

```
def bw_negative(filename):
    """
    This function creates a black and white negative of a bitmap image
    using the following parameters:
       filename is the name of the bitmap image
    """

    #Create the handle and then create a list of pixels.
    image = Image.open(filename)
    pixels = list(image.getdata())

    pixel[255] = 0
    pixel[0] = 255

    for i in range(255,0):
        for j in range(0,255):
            pixel[i] = j
            print pixels[i]


    image.putdata(pixels)
    image.save ('new.bmp')
```

Comment: Silly, arbitrary restrictions? Sounds like homework to me.

Comment: What he is trying to say: If the question is homework, tag it as such. The Stackoverflow community will not solve your homework for you, but we will provide you with hints that guide you to an *understanding* and thus the correct solution.

Comment: Where does the `Image`-type come from? Some library or custom?

Comment: "The opposite of white (255) is black (0) and vice versa. The opposite of a pixel with a value of 100 is 155." - which arithmetic operation will give you 0 for 255, 255 for 0 and 155 for 100?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python (image alteration)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4013517/python-image-alteration)

Answer (score 1):

Python is an interpreted language, which has the advantage that you can use an [interactive interpreter-session](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/interpreter.html) to try out things. Try to open the image file in an interactive session and look at the list you get from `list(image.getdata())`. Once you understand what that list contains, you can think about a way to invert the image.